# Syntax when pattern matching with tuples (Elixir)

Tags: pattern-matching, elixir

I'm following a tutorial and there's a basic syntax issue that I'm not sure about.

Sometimes when we are pattern matching (in say function arguments), we use `=` and match the left to the right.

However, at times I see `->` being used instead of `=`. For example this code:

`receive do {:result, filename} -> filename do`

I'm assuming this is wrong:

`receive do {:result, filename} = filename do`

Does this have to do with an anonymous function? Or maybe a special syntax for tuples(which are basically maps?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does this have to do with an anonymous function?

Nope.

> Or maybe a special syntax for tuples(which are basically maps?)

Not at all :)

`=` is a match operator, meaning RHO must match LHO, otherwise, [`MatchError`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MatchError.html) is raised.

```rb
{:ok, _} = {:ok, 42}
#⇒ {:ok, 42}

{:ok, _} = :error
** (MatchError) no match of right hand side value: :error
```

`->` should be read as *“if somewhat from the outer scope, depending on context, is matched to LHO, evaluate RHO.”*

```rb
case :error do
  {:ok, _} -> :never_reached
  _ -> :we_matched_error_through_match_all_clause
end
#⇒ :we_matched_error_through_match_all_clause
```

**¡NB!** Please note (credits to Diego Echeverri for mentioning this in comments) that if no one clause succeeded to match in the `->` example, `MatchError` is thrown. So `=` might be treated as *match exactly this!* and `->` as *match at least one of these and do what is stated on the right side of `->`*.

---

*Sidenote:* “tuples which are basically maps” tuples are by no mean maps.

Comment: I'd add that if no LHO is found (in the -> case) there's still a MatchError thrown. Maybe to make it more accessible explain what RHO and LHO is.

Comment: @DiegoEcheverri thanks, of course, I have updated the answer.

Comment: How about `<-`? :-)

Comment: @AdamMillerchip `<-` is pretty confusing because it expects a list to be filtered to what matches LHO in the case of `for` _but_ it expects a term to be matched against LHO _or_ returned in the case of `with`. So I would consider `<-` deserving a name **“less or minus”** for its diversity :)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I think about it. You can use pattern matching to "deconstruct" data as in:

```
 [x|xs] = mylist
```

You are getting an object and peeking at its structure, so you get access to its components. That's where the `=` is used.

For `receive` and `case _ do`, you are looking at "making decisions" or "control flow" based on the structure of the data you are manipulating. In your receive example, you are planning to return the filename, if the message received is "ok".

Comment: `42 = x` is a perfectly valid pattern matching that succeeds if `x` has indeed a value of `42`. And there are no “components,” whatever it means, in the integer literal.

Comment: Is valid, but doesn't feel idiomatic and doesn't answer the OP question. Feels like nitpicking.

Comment: Sure it does feel idiomatic :) In the application start code it is very common to do somewhat like `:ok = Application.ensure_all_started(...)`, which is essentially the same, to prevent launching the app in semi-valid state. I mean “destructuring” is one of the possible use-cases, but surely not the only one.

Comment: that's not the same as `42 = x` :) I know what you mean, good clarification, there's no need for "components" and confuses the pattern matching explanation. I'm a nitpicker myself :P :P